# Как восстановить поврежденный файл видео с помощью исправных?

Tags: кодировка, видео, восстановление, метаданные

Есть "здоровые" видеофайлы, а есть один поврежденный, кодировка которого не распознаётся, но формат тот же.
Можно ли анализируя здоровые файлы и выявляя среди них общее в метаданных поправить поврежденный?
И если да, то как вообще можно копаться в кодировке видео и метаданных? И есть ли идеи, кроме прогонки через энкодеры, т к ни одна программа не приняла файла?

Comment: Гадание по кофейной гуще. Может, у вас поврежденный мусором забит и восстанавливать там нечего. Читайте спецификаицю на форматы файлов, пробуйте руками прописать нужные значения...

Comment: если у Вас повреждены данные самого видео, то бесполезно; если только метаданные, то можно попробовать; но Вам правильно посоветовали - берите формат и изучайте; а что значит "здоровые"? - те же? копия? или другие?

Comment: @Dejsving даже если само видео побито - можно попробовать. Ну выпадет 1-2 кадра, не выкидывать же остальное? Но зависит от формата и объема повреждений, конечно.

Answer (score 0):

> Можно ли анализируя здоровые файлы и выявляя среди них общее в
>   метаданных поправить поврежденный?

Можно, разрешаю.

Если видео было в виде аш264, то поможет это: https://github.com/bookkojot/mp4fixer

Если видео было в чем-то другом - надо разбираться. Я восстанавливал АВИшки с медицинской камеры, зная параметры потока. Как правило, пишется отдельная утиль для восстановления